# project that works with folders on disk

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

end code which is a chatbot with watson assistant in nodejs

functions:

-receive the message in json format

-save the json message in folders on the pc disk

-I send documents hosted on the pc disk

-save documents on the pc disk

-create folders on local disk

I want to upload it to a cloud platform, so I don't have to run it manually

Since the code works with the pc disk, does it affect the deployment of the code in the cloud in any way?

Answer (score 1):

If your app is to run in the cloud, then you should use a cloud storage option for your application, or even a NOSQL database like Cloudant or Mongo. An app running in the cloud can save files to local file storage, but that data will disappear, when the app has to be restarted for any reason.

If your app is storing data then you will also need to consider data privacy concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will choose to use mongodb, I wanted to know if I can replicate the characteristics that I had using the local disk, such as creating folders within the database and saving files not only json but also spreadsheets, is it possible?